# Wordpress + Vimeo API | Find Specific Video Via URI

Tags: wordpress, get, request, vimeo, vimeo-api

So I am trying to utilize the Vimeo API in Wordpress to automatically embed a specific video, but the information I will have available is the URI. I created the following call in Postman which retrieves what I need, but I am struggling with how to authenticate via token to get this in Wordpress. I have a custom field in the post type that is "Vimeo URI" and want to use that in the call. Here is what I have in Postman:

GET [https://api.vimeo.com/videos?fields=uri,name,link&uris={VIDEOURI}](https://api.vimeo.com/videos?fields=uri,name,link&uris=%7BVIDEOURI%7D)

That returns (data replaced):

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 25,
    "paging": {
        "next": null,
        "previous": null,
        "first": "/videos?fields=uri%2Cname%2Clink&uris=%2Fvideos%2F441653190&page=1",
        "last": "/videos?fields=uri%2Cname%2Clink&uris=%2Fvideos%2F441653190&page=1"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "uri": "VIDEO URI",
            "name": "VIDEO NAME",
            "link": "VIDEO URL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how I started the request in functions.php:

```
$uri = the_field( 'vimeo_uri' );

$args_for_get = array(
        'headers' => array(
                'Authorization' => 'bearer INSERTED MY TOKEN HERE'
            ),
        'fields' => 'uri,name,link',
        'uri' => $uri
);

$url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos';

$request = wp_remote_get( $url, $args_for_get );

return load_request($request);

function load_request($response) {
    try {
        $json = json_decode( $response['body'] );
    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        $json = null;
    }
    return $json;
}

$json->data->link = $vimeolink;
```

This comes back with 400 bad request from Vimeo. Would appreciate any help on getting this to work. Also, should I be architecting this differently? The idea is for this call to go out on page load for each post that has the URI field, but maybe I should be scraping the data to a plugin instead and then retrieving the data from there?